# open an invalidate DB connection

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

i have a java function that must be executed every day at midnight, it is like a database update.

problem is i get an error

```
Exception d'E/S: Connection reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Exception d'E/S: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

i am using an oracle 11g database and hibernate.
is there a way to check if my DB connection is invalid how do i reopen one just to execute that function and the close it again.
it can cause server overload over time.

Comment: I'm clueless how this is related to JSF and HTTP sessions. This is a background job, right? How exactly is this affected by HTTP session timeout..? Are you manually triggering it by opening a web page or so? But that's then actually not a "background job" ..

Comment: it is a background job fired using spring quartz, it fires automatically at midnight it is not related to any web page, but what i understood from the internet it is because my jsf sessin is invalid

Comment: Ahh, you're confusing "DB session" with "HTTP session". These two things have completely nothing to do with each other.

Comment: i thought that jsf was also responsible for the DB session sorry